# Rails console : query to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, filter

I have a model Report in which I defined those columns:

```
 class Report < ActiveRecord::Base {
             :id => :uuid,
   :declarant_id => :uuid,
      :reference => :integer,
        :sent_at => :datetime,
  :updated_by_id => :uuid,
      :device_id => :string,
     :created_at => :datetime,
     :updated_at => :datetime,
    :is_archived => :boolean,
        :step_id => :uuid
}
```

and I want to filter the select query to get only the reports created 7 days ago, I defined this query related to some others inputs and methods :

```
r = Report.all.current.not_sent.only_finished_interventions.where("Report.created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)
```

it not works !

**when I do :**

```
r = Report.all.current.not_sent.only_finished_interventions
```

I get the the requested reports.

can some one help to add the filter of 7.days.ago ?

***I got this error in the rails c :***

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "report" LINE 1: ... AND
>   "activities"."finished_at" IS NOT NULL) AND (Report.cre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

**`.where("Reports.created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)`**

Just make **Report** plural.

But I think **Reports.** is not necessary in your query bcs you don't join tables, so this should work too:

```
**`.where("created_at >= ?", 7.days.ago)`**
```

Comment: That's it ! Thanks